# Java Pig Latin program for school

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my homework for school. We are supposed to write a program that allows a user to input a sentence and then have it translated and displayed in Pig Latin. The display will show the original word on the left side, then a tab, and finally the translated word. I am stuck at the part where the characters in front of the first vowel are moved to the end of the word. For example, in the word "trouble" I can't figure out how to move the 'tr' to the end of the word to make it "oubletr". I would appreciate any help that points me in the right direction. Below is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class PigLatinTranslator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare string for userSentence and pigLatin
    String userSentence; 

    //Assign vowels to char
    char a = 'a';
    char e = 'e';
    char i = 'i';
    char o = 'o';
    char u = 'u';

    //Ask user for input and save to userSentence variable
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
    userSentence = input.nextLine();

    //Split the userSentence into an array
    String[] userWords = userSentence.split(" ");

    //This will go through the words and locate vowels
    for(int k = 0; k < userWords.length; k++) {

        //Change letters in userWords to lower case
        String temp = userWords[k].toLowerCase();
        char c = temp.charAt(0); 

            //If first character is equal to a vowel
            if(c == a || c == e || c == i || c == o || c == u) {
                System.out.println(temp + "\t" + temp + "way");
                }

            else {
                //print the ones that start with a consonant
                System.out.println(temp + "\t" + temp + "ay");
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know what is pig latin or what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @m0skit0 - igpay atinlay isway away umerousha ofway eakingspay.  [inklay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin).

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in the word "trouble" I can't figure out how to move the
> 'tr' to the end of the word to make it "oubletr".

Do it as follows:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "trouble", newStr = "";
        String strLowerCase = str.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char ch = strLowerCase.charAt(i);
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
                newStr = str.substring(i) + str.substring(0, i);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
oubletr
```

**Notes:**

1. Convert the string into the lower case and compare its characters with the lower case vowel letters (i.e. `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`). Alternatively, you can convert the string into the upper case and compare its characters with the upper case vowel letters (i.e. `A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, `U`).
2. `String::substring(start)` returns a string with all characters starting from the index, `start`. `String::substring(start, end)` returns a string with all characters starting from the index, `start` till the index, `end - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easier and use the contains() method so you don't have to do two loops...

```
String vowels = "aeiou"; // idk if y counts who cares
String message = "trouble";

for (int letter = 0; letter < message.length(); letter++) {
  if (vowels.contains("" + message.charAt(letter))) {
    message = message.substring(letter) + message.substring(0, letter);
    break;
  }
}

System.out.println(message); // oubletr
```